# customising date range for a graph using matplotlib.pyplot in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: date, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

please note im a novice and i am using Juypter Notebook. i have imported pandas, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot. I have also

df=pd.read_excel

i now have the following code:

```
y=df['AXX Index']
x=df['Date']
plt.plot(x,('2020-01-01','2020-06-01'),y)
```

I want to know why this wont work.. and plot a graph between the specified period stated. my date runs for 5 years and i want to the plot 2020/01/01 to 2020/06/01

this is what i get:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1446,) and (2,)